# DataGridView TextBox cell Editing, Change Enter Key to Act Like Tab

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am re-asking this question as I now have some code to go with my issue (I deleted the old Question).

Basically when the enter key is pressed while editing a textbox cell, I would like it to act like a Tab press (Next Column in current Row Instead of Next row same column).

My problem is most of what I have tried so far doesn't work, This was my current attempted solution however.

This code is supposed to change which cell is being edited/Selected.

```
    private void PreTranslateDGV_KeyPressEvent(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl a = (DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl) sender;
        //a.PreviewKeyDown -= PreviewKeyDownEventHandler (dataGridView1_PreviewKeyDown)
        MyDataGridView s = (MyDataGridView) a.EditingControlDataGridView;
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
            int newRow;
            int newColumn;
            if (s.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == s.ColumnCount - 1)         // it's a last column, move to next row;
            {
                newRow = s.CurrentCell.RowIndex + 1;
                newColumn = 0;

                if (newRow == s.RowCount)
                    return; // ADD new row or RETURN (depends of your purposes..)
            }
            else                // just change current column. row is same
            {
                newRow = s.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
                newColumn = s.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex + 1;
            }

            s.CurrentCell = s.Rows[newRow].Cells[newColumn];
        }
    }
```

This is the code that Adds the Above event to the Cell's textbox

```
private void PreTranslateDGV_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl tb = (DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl)e.Control;
        tb.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler (PreTranslateDGV_KeyPressEvent);
    }
```

Most of this was code I found from StackOverflow as I have been trying to get it working for a while.

If anyone Knows how to properly Get the "Enter" Keypress from within a datagridview, While editing a cell please help.

PS: I Read on an MSDN forum (lost link) That when Editing a textbox cell, When you press enter it Stops editing. Which would explain why my code above doesn't fire On Enter, but it fires on everything else.

I am now attempting to do this by over-riding the processcmdkey

```
    class MyDataGridView : KryptonDataGridView
{
    protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
    {
        if ((keyData == Keys.Enter) && (this.EditingControl != null))
        {
            return false;
        }
        //for the rest of the keys, proceed as normal
        return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
    }
}
```

But no matter what I seem to Return, the Enter key isn't passed to the KeyPressEvent.

Answer (score 1):

After much, annoying trouble. Here the solution I am currently using:

```
 private void PreTranslateDGV_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl a = (DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl) sender;
        //a.PreviewKeyDown -= PreviewKeyDownEventHandler (dataGridView1_PreviewKeyDown)
        MyDataGridView s = (MyDataGridView) a.EditingControlDataGridView;
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            int newRow;
            int newColumn;
            if (s.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == s.ColumnCount - 1)         // it's a last column, move to next row;
            {
                newRow = s.CurrentCell.RowIndex + 1;
                newColumn = 0;

                if (newRow == s.RowCount)
                    s.Rows.Add(1); // ADD new row or RETURN (depends of your purposes..)
            }
            else                // just change current column. row is same
            {
                newRow = s.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
                newColumn = s.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex + 1;
            }
            s.CurrentCell = s.Rows[newRow].Cells[newColumn];
        }
    }
    private void PreTranslateDGV_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl tb = (DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl)e.Control;
        tb.PreviewKeyDown -= PreTranslateDGV_PreviewKeyDown;
        tb.PreviewKeyDown += PreTranslateDGV_PreviewKeyDown;

        //e.Control.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(PreTranslateDGV_KeyPressEvent);
    }
```

I changed the KeyPressEvent, to a PreviewKeyDown Event. Which fires before ProcessCmdKey Gets input. Using this and my modified datagridview I was able to Get the Enter key to Act like Tab, while Inside a cell.

```
   class MyDataGridView : KryptonDataGridView
{
    protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
    {
        if ((keyData == Keys.Enter) && (this.EditingControl != null))
        {
            return true;
        }
        //for the rest of the keys, proceed as normal
        return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
    }
}
```

When ProcessCmdKey is given the Enter Key, It Immediately returns "true" to state that it has been handled. *which it has by the PreviewkeyDown event*

Hopefully this helps other people. I'm not sure how many other ways there are to do this, But this method worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I reused the [idea of inheriting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40334483/806690) from `DataGridView`, but attempt to directly solve the task in the `ProcessCmdKey` override.

```
class PerfectDataGridView : DataGridView {
    protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData) {
        if ((keyData == Keys.Enter) &&
            (EditingControl != null) &&
            (CurrentCell.RowIndex == RowCount - 1)) {

            SendKeys.Send("{TAB}");
            return true;
        }
        return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
    }
}
```